# apollo-client - can I adjust apolloLinks dynamically after apollo-client instantiation?

Tags: apollo, apollo-client, apollo-link

How can I update the token during runtime in an instantiated apollo-client instance?

```
const middleware = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
    operation.setContext({
        headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token || null)});
        return forward(operation);
    });


apollo.createNamed(id, {
    link: from([logoutLink, middleware, http]),
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});
```

The apollo instance has a link property, which itself is a ApolloLink instance, which has the concat method.

```
apollo.getclient().link.concat()
```

But calling that concat returns a new ApolloLink instance. Is there a way to update the client instance with this new ApolloLink?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to create a new `ApolloLink` -- you pass a function to `ApolloLink`'s constructor that's ran each time a request is made, so just handle that logic inside the function:

```
const middleware = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
  const headers = new HttpHeaders()
  const token = getTokenFromWherever()
  headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token)
  operation.setContext({ header })
})
```

Comment: I am applying a use case where in my app some graphql queries not need to send authorization headers. I have set context, how do I remove authorization header when making those specific requests grapql